# Minimizing peak memory usage while performing a series of operations on std containers

Tags: c++, memory, temporary-objects

I have a "pipeline" of functions that produce a final result along with some intermediate results. I am looking for a way to reduce the peak memory by cleaning up the intermediate results as soon as they are no longer needed.

This is the way it looks if I don't care about memory of intermediate results. B, C, D, E, and F are all `std` containers with over a million objects each.

```
void A::getF(F &f) {
  B b;
  C c;
  computeBAndC(b, c);
  D d;
  computeD(b, c, d);
  // b and c no longer needed
  E e;
  computeE(d, e);
  // d no longer needed
  computeF(e, f);
}
```

These are the ways I came up with:

A. Use `new` and `delete` to cleanup once they are no longer needed. But, does it make sense to use new and delete for std containers?

```
void A::getF(F &f) {
  B *b = new B;
  C *c = new C;
  computeBAndC(b, c);
  D *d = new D;
  computeD(b, c, d);
  // b and c no longer needed
  delete b;
  delete c;
  E e;
  computeE(d, e);
  // d no longer needed
  delete d;
  computeF(e, f);
}
```

B. Use the std container's `swap` function to clear their memory after use.

```
void A::getF(F &f) {
  B b;
  C c;
  computeBAndC(b, c);
  D d;
  computeD(b, c, d);
  // b and c no longer needed
  B().swap(b);
  C().swap(c);
  E e;
  computeE(d, e);
  // d no longer needed
  D().swap(d);
  computeF(e, f);
}
```

C. Use blocks.

```
void A::computeF(F &f) {
  E e;
  {
    D d;
    {
      B b;
      C c;
      computeBAndC(b, c);
      computeD(b, c, d);
      // b and c no longer needed
    }
    computeE(d, e);
    // d no longer needed
  }
  computeF(e, f);
}
```

D. Restructure so that the intermediate results get deleted at the end of function scope:

```
void A::getF(F &f) {
  E e;
  getE(e);
  computeF(e, f);
}

void A::getE(E &e) {
  D d;
  getD(d);
  computeE(d, e);
}

void A::getD(D &d) {
  B b;
  C c;
  computeBAndC(b, c);
  computeD(b, c, d);
}
```

What are the pros and cons of these approaches? Will these really reduce peak memory usage? Is there a better way?

Comment: No, only C++98 unfortunately.

Comment: To compute a single element of say `d`, do you need all elements of `b` and `c` for that? If nota form of lazy evaluation could be your friend, though the limitation of C++98 (really? Not even 03!? This is an 17 years old standard) makes this harder than necessary.

Comment: Can any of the computations be done in-place. i.e instead of creating a whole new container convert a previous container element-by-element into the new container?

Comment: @DanielJour: Yes, I do. Could you point me to the lazy evaluation you mention? It would be good to know.

Comment: @ChrisDrew: Thanks for the suggestion. computeE and computeF could indeed be done in place. D, E, and F are all unordered_maps of the same keys, but different value types (set, int, and float). Would I use a union as the value type to be able to do it in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I would choose the option D because given that there's some connection between some of your variables, extracting this code into functions not only would address your memory concerns, but would also better document your intentions using your code itself (I believe you could come up with good self-explanatory names in your code). The only issue is of course the performance if you use a nicer approach to the function signatures (assuming you don't control the `compute` functions: i.e.

```
E A::computeE(const D& d) {
    E e;
    computeE(d, e);
    return E;
}
```

I understand from your comment you can only use C++98 which doesn't have move semantics. However, the compilers have long been able to perform the named return value optimization - and in your case I would try to test the abilities of your compiler to use NRVO (and copy elision), and if it's good - use a more natural (IMO) signature I outlined - otherwise I'd use your option D.

Answer (score -2):

If you're storing pointers to objects in those containers, then deleting them (or just letting them go out of scope) won't free up the memory the objects are using, only the memory for the container itself. You'd have to delete each object in the container as well.

Otherwise, yes, using new and delete on STD containers makes perfect sense. It'll also mean allocating the memory for them on the heap instead of the stack, which is probably wise as while the stack is good for quick allocation, you can run out if you dump too much on it. You might also wind up with paging issues.

To really solve your problem, though, it would help to know more about what you're doing. Do you really need to be using STD containers? Could you use an array instead? Are the objects in the container unique to each container, or are they the same bunch of objects being rearranged into different containers? Is there a way to break up the operation into smaller data sets rather than running through a series of containers like that?

Comment: The containers are storing pointers to objects. The objects they are pointing to will be released much later. It is ok if that memory is not released now. I just want the memory used by the pointers themselves to be free, since there will be a lot of them. The std containers include stacks, sets, and unordered_sets. They are pointing to nodes in a graph. The operations include topological sort, graph coloring, then using the topological order and color to traverse again and compute a metric for each node in the graph, then sorting the nodes according to this metric and selecting a subset, etc.

Comment: An STD container is pretty small, regardless of the number of elements stored in it or even the size of those elements. (Try `sizeof(std::vector<int[100]>)`, for example.) The container structure itself contains only a few pointers; the data itself is allocated dynamically. So your comment about the advantage of heap-allocating the container makes little sense. And changing to arrays (which is almost certainly a bad idea) will do nothing with respect to the actual question being asked, which is about managing the objects.